# How to delete an image when updated a new one in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I recently started coding with Codeigniter, so fairly new, even to php.

I made this app where a user can update his profile image. But when I go back to uploads I still see old image there.

Can't figure out how to perform this.

Controller:

```
public function profile_image_check() {
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
    $username = $this->session->userdata('v_member_username');

    $url  = $this->do_upload();
    //$this->load->model('admin/my_profile_model');
    //$title = $_POST['title'];
    $this->my_profile_model->update_profile_image($url, $username);
    }
}
private function do_upload() {
    $type = explode('.', $_FILES['profile_image']['name']);
    $type = $type[count($type)-1];
    $url = "./uploads/profile/".uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type;
    if(in_array($type, array('jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'jpg')))
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_image']['tmp_name']))
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_image']['tmp_name'], $url));
            return $url;
    return '';
}
```

Model:

```
function update_profile_image($url, $username){
    //$this->db->set('title', $title);
    $this->db->set('profile_image', $url);
    $this->db->where('v_member_username', $username);
    $this->db->update('vbc_registered_members');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to used the php `unlink($filename)` function to delete the file after updating it.

Here some ref. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_unlink.asp Hope that helps.